# C# change the sorting algorithm of a list

Tags: c#, sorting

Is there a way I can change the sorting algorithm of a `List<string>` in C#?

If I have a list

```
List<string> Names = new List<string>();
```

When sorting I call

```
Names.Sort();
```

Is the a way I can override the default algorithm that is used?

Second question

What about the build in sorting of a webgrid in ASP.NET MVC3?
The Webgrid has a build in sorting, if you specify `canSort=true` you can click on the header and rows will be sorted alphabetically. is there a way I can change that too?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to, for example, use heapsort instead of quicksort? Or do you just want to order the items in a different way? If that's the case, how do you want to sort them?

Answer (score 2):

There are overloads to `List<>.Sort()` that accepts custom comparers.

- [Sort(Comparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx)
- [Sort(IComparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, this will solve my list sorting problem. But do you have an idea about the WebGrid sorting? is there a method that I can overload? or a sorting event?